# Empty fields causes mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

I have  a form that has several fields that are optional.  When the mysql query saves the data from the form it fails if any of the fields are are left blank.

What is the best way of getting around this?  I would prefer the field in the database to remain empty rather than having to enter data just to keep the query happy.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO s_num_serialz (id, name, date_entered, created_by, account_name, type, supply_type, covered_by_support, install_date, job_number, replacement_for) VALUES ('$id', '$serial_num', NOW(), '$diary_id', '$account', '$type', '$supply_type', $support_cover, '$dispatch_date', '$job_num', '$old_serial_num')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
```

It's a straight forward insert but if one of the values, say $job_number, is empty the query will fail

Comment: Add more details like a sample of your code and the query being run.

Comment: This is too general. There's no such general problem with MySQL, it depends on how you use it and what the exact error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well check if a field is empty after recieving

```
$r=trim($_POST["something"])
if($r!=''){
  //code goes here    
}
```

If you are using the query of form

```
Insert into table (..,..,...) values (...,...,)
```

try switching to

```
Insert into table set column1='', column2=''
```

And add some code to help us answer because it **should work**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for youbanswer.  I have added my code, its a straight forward insert but if a field is left empty the error says there was an error in the syntax where and it will show ,, (the commas seperating the empty field).  Remove the value from the query or put data in the field and it works.  I will try the other query type you suggested

Comment: you forgot the ' ' around $support_cover

Comment: $support_cover is an int hence the missing ''